# I can't write into the Control register for parallel port on window 7 64 bit platform, why?

Tags: 64-bit, driver, hardware, parallel-port

I am using inpout32.dll to deal with parallel port on my pc. I find I can change value of control register (0x37a) on windows 7 32bit, but I can't on 64bit.

Anyone knows the reason?

The home page of the dll is http://www.highrez.co.uk/

I paste the source code for inpoutx64.sys as follows, it's pretty simple, just call WRITE_PORT_UCHAR system api, any differences for 64bit version and 32bit version of this function?

```
NTSTATUS hwinterfaceDeviceControl(IN PDEVICE_OBJECT DeviceObject, IN PIRP pIrp)
{
PIO_STACK_LOCATION  stkloc;
NTSTATUS            ntStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS; 
struct              tagPhys32Struct Phys32Struct;

PUCHAR              cData;
PUSHORT             sData;
PULONG              lData;
PUSHORT             address;

ULONG               inBuffersize;   
ULONG               outBuffersize;  
ULONG               inBuf;         
PVOID               CtrlBuff;

stkloc = IoGetCurrentIrpStackLocation( pIrp );
inBuffersize = stkloc->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.InputBufferLength;
outBuffersize = stkloc->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.OutputBufferLength;

CtrlBuff    = pIrp->AssociatedIrp.SystemBuffer;
cData  = (PUCHAR) CtrlBuff;
sData  = (PUSHORT) CtrlBuff;
lData  = (PULONG) CtrlBuff;
address = (PUSHORT) CtrlBuff;

switch ( stkloc->Parameters.DeviceIoControl.IoControlCode )
 {
    case IOCTL_READ_PORT_UCHAR:
        if ((inBuffersize >= 2) && (outBuffersize >= 1)) 
        {
            UCHAR value;
            value = READ_PORT_UCHAR((PUCHAR)address[0]);
            cData[0] = value;
        } 
        else 
        {   
            ntStatus = STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL;
        }
        pIrp->IoStatus.Information = sizeof(UCHAR); 
        ntStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;

        break;
    case IOCTL_WRITE_PORT_UCHAR:
        if (inBuffersize >= 3) 
        {
            WRITE_PORT_UCHAR((PUCHAR)address[0], cData[2]); //Byte 0,1=Address Byte 2=Value
            pIrp->IoStatus.Information = 10;
        } 
        else 
        {
            ntStatus = STATUS_BUFFER_TOO_SMALL;
            pIrp->IoStatus.Information = 0; 
            ntStatus = STATUS_SUCCESS;
        }
        break;
```

Comment: Is that the same PC or different? I'm asking because not every PC has a parallel port these days. Also, that DLL, does it need to talk to a driver that you need to install? Is it possible that you have it installed on 32-bit system only? [This page](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/inpout32/) suggests there may be a problem I'm describing.

Comment: Yes, I'm talking a same pc which can boot onto 2 OS. I'm using asus h61 mainboard. I think I installed and run the dll properly. The dll and the driver attatched with it both open sourced. the home page is http://www.highrez.co.uk/ .

Comment: You can comb through other questions mentioning `inpout32` or ask the author/maintainer. I haven't used the DLL and I don't know what can be wrong other than you somehow not running `InstallDriver.exe` or not running elevated / as admin.

Comment: I can read&write data register, so I think the driver is installed and running.

Comment: Is there any error code or log or anything?

Answer (score -1):

I think you have some knowledge about hardware architecture, well, 64bit architecture change completely, and change register values can be protected for the hardware level or software level.

try to share what you want to do, Your ask don't left clear what you main deal.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer. You're risking -1's.

Comment: i know, i have less than 50 but that ask was a lil vague. thanks for your care

Comment: I remember seeing questions related to this (or similar) DLL in the past um... 6 years or so. If you'd googled the DLL (as I just did), you would've found the description of how it works/installs and some additional info on compatibility issues. Googling the DLL yields more helpful info than this answer of yours.

Comment: in fact I'm communicating with a data collection card through parallel port. I need to read data, status,control registers and write data,control registers. But I find I can't write into control register on 64bit windows 7,